# Mount React Portal somewhere the current rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-portal

I'm trying to mount a React Portal whose node is the member of current rendering component. As per shown in the below code, I've to forcefully re-render it by setting a state in the `componentDidMount` which seems to be an anti-pattern to me.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import FormProduct from 'containers/FormProduct';
import Portal from 'shared/Portal';

class Users extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.productForm = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      mounted: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ mounted: true});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="mt-20" ref={this.productForm}></div>
          {this.state.mounted && <Portal node={this.productForm.current}>
            <FormProduct />
          </Portal>}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

How can we achieve it in the first rendering?

Comment: So portal as a regular react node?

Comment: Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component. (https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) It is NOT your case!!